# Re-making Logo in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Would it be possible to re-make this logo using CSS so I can have it as text?

http://acquiremedia.com/templates/amc/images/icon/acquire-media.png

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Thanks for marking down a perfectly legitimate question. Now it won't get answered.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Paulie, yes I agree, stackoverflow is not a service. This is why I attempted building it myself through JavaScript but had no luck and would like to know if it would be possible to build in CSS. How is this not a legitimate question? I am not asking someone to do it for me, I am asking whether or not it is possible.

Comment: "_Thanks for marking down a perfectly legitimate question. Now it won't get answered._" This is not a legitimate question because you didn't follow any of the site's guidelines for asking a question here and weren't going to get much attention even if you had upvotes. Also, the answer to your question is yes, it would be possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in CSS. You won't even need JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.I will take this into account when asking future questions. I am still new hear and I am still learning the ropes.

Comment: Another option would be something like this - https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/ but support might not be great, view in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/b3jtc7v5/1/

```
<h1>acquire<span>media</span></h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 { 
    font-family:arial; 
    color:#000; 
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

h1 span { 
    color:lime; 
}

h1:before { 
    content:""; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:75px;
    color:lime;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:lime;
    border-radius:50%;
}


h1 span:after { 
   content:""; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:180px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

Using the `:before` pseudo element we can add a small circle and position it over the the `i` in the text.